# Handling very precise numbers in R

Tags: r, math, precision

I am using R to try and solve the formula
[image] where [image]  and
[image] is the standard normal distribution function. The problem I run into is that some values of *g* are very small or coded in R as 0 so that the given solution is Inf. An example of when *g* is coded as 0 when it should be positive is given in the line of code below.

```
pnorm(29.1,0,1) - pnorm(29,0,1) #this returns a value of 0
```

In light of this problem I have two questions. First, is there a mathematical trick which can be used to get a positive number from the above code? I know there is a `pnorm` argument `log.p=TRUE` which returns the log of the probability. Perhaps that could come in handy?

My second question is, in the case where I have a positive but very small *g*, is there a mathematical trick for ensuring the log of the ratio of *f* and *g* is finite?

Comment: This is likely a floating-point precision issue

Comment: There is nothing that can be done. The value is practically 0. Note that `pnorm(29.1)` is practically 1. Note that for `P(X<=8.2924) = 1` so whether you have `29.1` or `19` or any other number greater than `8.2824` you will get a 1

Comment: Why don't you take `f'(29)` and divide it directly by `dnorm(29, 0 , 1)`

Comment: I would also advise you to always reverse `pnorm()` function in R to mitigate this rounding issue: `pnorm(-29,0,1) - pnorm(-29.1,0,1)`. Since the function is symmetric, it's ok.

Comment: Great points @Alex, I was writing my derivative answer as you posted your comments. But with numerical precision being better close to 0, your second comment may be sufficient.

Comment: pnorm is computed through an approximation algorithm. The difference between pnorm(29.1,0,1) and pnorm(29,0,1) will likely be far too noisy to be meaningful regardless of what precision is used to represent the computed values because the function used to compute the values has a certain precision.

Comment: From pnorm code documentation: " The main computation evaluates near-minimax approximations derived from those in "Rational Chebyshev approximations for the error function" by W. J. Cody, Math. Comp., 1969, 631-637.  This transportable program uses rational functions that theoretically approximate the normal distribution function to at least 18 significant decimal digits.  The accuracy achieved depends on the arithmetic system, the compiler, the intrinsic functions, and proper selection of the machine-dependent constants."

Comment: Thanks a lot for these comments! They definitely are helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in answers and comments, you really only need to compute `log(g)`.

One solution is to use **logspace addition/subtraction**, which uses a nice trick to compute `log(exp(x) ± exp(y))` accurately.

```r
DPQ::logspace.sub(pnorm(29.1, log.p = TRUE), pnorm(29, log.p = TRUE))
## [1] -424.8435
```

@Alex points out that if we look at the (symmetric) opposite tail by reversing the signs, so that we are subtracting a **very small** number from another very small number, the round-off error isn't a problem:

```r
log(pnorm(-29,0,1) - pnorm(-29.1,0,1))
##  -424.8435
```

Comparing the derivative-based estimate from @GregorThomas:

```r
dnorm(29, log = TRUE) + log(0.1)
## [1] -423.7215
```

Checking these solutions with the `Rmpfr` package:

```r
library(Rmpfr)
x1 <- mpfr(29.1, 1000)  ### 1000-bit precision
x2 <- mpfr(29.0, 1000)
log(pnorm(x1) - pnorm(x2))
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  1000   bits 
## [1] -424.843525917118620331088762368642820931865149932737039093516330881321230653835360169156688142607902967369067320263733953321675429119215305576014352760866238194504221709021981332048618426550583180796866417925580695487036011142823944123174363138216647098415472494704193913895461975221571930136768807682871
```

So it looks like @GregorThomas's solution is pretty close, but the other two solutions are better.

Comment: Very cool! I've never seen DPQ or Rmpfr before.

Comment: `logspace_add`, `logspace_sub`, and `logspace_sum` are actually defined at the C level in base R, but not exposed ... https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/nmath/pgamma.c#L217-L243

Answer (score 2):

`log(f / g) = log(f) - log(g)`, so you need to calculate `log(g)`.

You have `g = pnorm(x + d) - pnorm(x)`.

The density function (`dnorm()` in R)is the derivative of the CDF (`pnorm()`). This means that `dnorm(x) = (pnorm(x + delta) - pnorm(x)) / delta` as `delta` approaches 0. So for small `delta` we can approximate `dnorm(x) * delta = pnorm(x + delta) - pnorm(x)`. Thus `g(x) = dnorm(x) * d` (approximately), and `log(g(x)) = log(dnorm(x)) + log(d)`.

Use `dnorm(29, log = TRUE) + log(0.1)` in your calculation as `log(g)`.